# Creating a Row Auto Incrementing Coprocessor for HBase

Tags: java, ruby, hadoop, row, hbase

I've been trying to find an efficient way of creating an auto increment co-processor for the row identifiers in HBase but all my searching has been leading me nowhere.

What I want can be best exemplified by [this class in github which contains the method **incrementRow(table_name,amount)**](https://github.com/jeanlescure/hbase_thrift_ruby/blob/master/lib/hbase_thrift_ruby.rb)

How would I write this as a Java co-processor?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [Ruby]?

Comment: Because of the example link I posted is written in ruby. So I basically want to convert that ruby code to java.

Answer (score 0):

The thrift API allows you to use the increment mutation: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-thrift/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift?view=markup (see line 585). Increments are atomics, and rock.

Comment: I have actually used Thrift a little following [this tutorial](http://www.jlescure.com/blog/hadoop-for-rubyists-quick-intro-to-hbase/) and also I have been using [this ruby gem](https://github.com/jeanlescure/hipster_sql_to_hbase) for my project for the time being since when you do an INSERT statement it somehow does auto increment the row identifier.

But I'm still looking for a java co-processor way to do it and haven't found one. I just wish I could use Thrift on java.

Comment: You don't need a coprocessor in order to do this, Increment in more efficient: if the region holding your increment is decommissionned, your coprocessor will be unavaible and you will end with a null row key. Why reinvent the whell?